# Blazor - How to save the boolean state (true/false) in the browser so it does not change when reloading the page?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I have two different views (List and Cards), and I want to save the toggled one so that it does not change when reloading the page in Blazor / C#.

```
<p>Testing-Function</p>
<button @onclick="ToggleListCard">Testing-button</button>


private bool CardIsActive = true;
private void ToggleListCard() {
    if (CardIsActive == true)
    {
        CardIsActive = false;
        OnCardListToggled.InvokeAsync(CardIsActive = false);
        Console.WriteLine("True Toggled!");     
    }                                       
    else                                   
    {
          CardIsActive = true;
          OnCardListToggled.InvokeAsync(CardIsActive = true);
          Console.WriteLine("False Toggled!");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Toggled!");
}
```

Comment: Save it in browser's localStorage/sessionStorage. https://jonhilton.net/blazor-tailwind-dark-mode-local-storage/

Comment: I used this link to come up with this code that I shared, but it is not saving it! Did I do something wrong?  @HPSingh

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage library to save an object to browser local storage and read it every time you want.

Alternative way : use JS interop to get and save in local storage

JS interop : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Local storage : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: FYI link only answers are considered "bad", maybe share the knowledge that is provided within the links in case they die

Comment: When I use the first way suggested above, i get this issue: "InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'localStorage' on type 'Project.Pages.Home'. There is no registered service of type 'Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService'." . Any idea about how I can register the service of type 'Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService'?  @SaJJaD.AgEnT.47

Comment: if you using blazor server add code below to Startup.cs this 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
}

add code below if you using blazor webassembly

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

    builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}

Comment: read setup section of the library for more information https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage